# Negative DBE/Degree of Hydrogen Deficiency?

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy

I tried calculating the Index of Hydrogen Deficiency for C6H15SiCl, and I get negative one. I get this value by subtracting the number of chlorine and hydrogen atoms from that of the carbon atoms, and then adding one. I don't think I am supposed to do anything with the number of silicon atoms.  Is this correct/normal?

Comment: SiH4 has the same IHD as CH4, so Si  should be treated as C.
https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Fundamentals/Index_of_Hydrogen_Deficiency_(IHD)   Always think  thoroughly about possible answers to your question and search for them
before asking.

Comment: In case of doubts, analy, how is hydrogen deficiency changed, if H- of  -CH2- are replaced by other atoms or their groups.